# Are observables syntax sugar of promises? In what essence they are compiled under the hood?

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs, observable

Are observables syntax sugar of promises? 
In what essence they are compiled under the hood?

Comment: What does "compiled under the hood" mean? Javascript is not a compiled language so nothing is compiled

Comment: I think it's a good question, personally. Yes, it's not compiled, but that's not the point, I don't think Max actually means that.

Comment: @Liam first, js is most of the time compiled JIT, then the question is about rxjs Observables. Myself not a ninja in rxjs, but rxjs is written in TypeScript which If I'm not mistaken gets compiled to actual javascript.

Comment: @Kaiido It gets transpiled, which is quite different, but I see where you're coming from.

Comment: Nothing is compiled (JIT or otherwise). But ignoring that. What are you asking? do observerbles use promises? Yes because observable are not in the ECMA spec where as promises are. So node does not understand (natively) what an observable is. rxjs is a library that offers additional functionality to Javascript (like all libraries do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question. The answer is no. To understand this, it's best to look at the [toPromise](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/compat/operator/toPromise.ts) method, which is in the prototype of the `Observable` object.

This method converts an Observable into a promise, which indicates that it's not a promise in the first place.